# Accessing group elements in groupby

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, groupby

I had a doubt about groupby operations. Lets suppose I have grouped my data based on one column and got 5 groups as output. I know that we can iterate over these groups and apply functions to them as a whole. But can I access the elements of each group (for example I have 5 groups each having 5 rows, can I access those rows one by one). I want to apply a function that compares two rows of a single group based on one or more parameters of the rows belonging to that group.

```
Year   Rank    Final_Score    Team
2000    1           50          A
2000    2           35          B       
2000    3           65          C
2003    3           20          B
2003    1           53          C
2003    2           44          A
```

If I have grouped by years such that the two groups would be group for year 2000 and 2003 respectively. I want to compare row1 and row2 of group 2000 by comparing their attribute Final Score and for this I need to access each row in the group. Can I do that by **grouby()**?

Comment: Something with `df.groupby().shift()`?

Comment: Just looked up what shift() is but it won't solve my problem because I want to access the rows in a group formed by groupby

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what `groupby().shift()` does? Are you sure you weren't looking at `df.shift()`?

Comment: Okay I may have mistaken between the two of them then. Thanks for the help!